# How do I set up bfgminer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration, bfgminer

How may I know if I've set up my bfgminer correctly? I don't have any hardwares (cause I'm like pretty broke and it costs a lot) so how may I know if bfgminer is properly working?

How do I know if I earned something? I'm completely new to this and no clear instructions either.

Comment: I've edited your post down to one core question. I did this because making posts cover fewer topics makes them easier to search for. It's OK to [re-ask](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) your other questions. You can look at the edit history to see the removed part instead of retyping it.

Answer (score 0):

bfgminer requires some sort of hardware to mine on. This is usually an FPGA or ASIC, though GPUs can be (unprofitably) used.

> how may I know if bfgminer is properly working?

Typically, bfgminer will show output in the command line showing that it is working. Also, the pool that you are mining in will show accepted shares from your worker.